# A script that tells something to disappaer once I click outside of it on anything

Tags: jquery, ajax, show-hide

Okay I have a form search on my site that when clicked loads the search results into a hidden iframe that shows. This is the iframe:

```
<iframe class="slidingDiv" id="frame-content-left2" name="search-box" 
        src="content.html"></iframe>
```

This is the button that toggles it show state on/off:

```
<input type="submit" value="Search" class="send-button" />
```

Now when the above iframe shows the div with page content that the site's navigation links load into disappears. This is the div:

```
<div id="myDiv">some content here</div>
```

Now I have a bit of problem because when I click on the navigations on the left you can't see the div that it is loaded into because it is hidden. What I want is to somehow tell the iframe with the search results to disappear once I click outside of it on something, like a link or blank area, making this div:

```
<div id="myDiv">some content here</div>
```

reappear.

This is the code that I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.send-button').click(function() {
        if ($('#frame-content-left2').is(':visible')) {
            $('#frame-content-left2').hide(2000);
            $('#myDiv').show(2000);
        }
        else {
            $('#frame-content-left2').show(2000);
            $('#myDiv').hide(2000);
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach a click listener to the document and look at the target for the event.  If the target is something that should make the div appear, make it appear.

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    if(e.target.id !== 'myDiv'){
        $('#myDiv').show();
    }
});
```

Something to that extent will perform the action you're looking for.

Comment: it partly works. The div that I want to appear (myDiv) appears but the iframe does not disappear. When the target (width id="myDiv") appears I want the iframe with the search results to disappear.

Comment: you've got the framework.  go and modify it so you have your desired functionality.  add a line to hide the iframe, and you've got what you need.

Comment: That's what i'm trying. I kinda new to this.

Comment: `show()` has a corresponding `hide()` function.  (And a `toggle()` which flips between states).  So, if you wanted to hide your iframe, you could call `.hide()` on the selector given the id for the element `$('#frame-content-left2').hide()`

Comment: No dice. I am running into some issues. I just can't seem to get it to work.